# apache solr query and filter query

Tags: solr, fuzzy-search

A csv file has been indexed in solr(8.9) with field as 'food', 'color' and other fields.

Both food and color fields have fieldType : text_general with multivalued as false.
Fuzzy-search has been done on field 'food' and exact match has been done on field 'color'.

Field 'food' and 'color' are configured in managed schema as follows

```
<field name="food" type="text_general" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="color" type="text_general" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

20 milion documents have been indexed in solr. There are 20 distinct values for 'color' field. 1 milion document(out of 20
milion documents) has value 'whilte' for field 'color'.

Following query has been executed.

```
curl -G http://localhost:8983/solr/QueryPerformenceCore/select --data-urlencode "q=(food:'cheese~' OR food:'paneer~' OR food:'milk~')" --data-urlencode "fq=color:white"
```

Now for the above query fuzzy search over field 'food will executed on 1 milion document or will it executed on 20 milion
documents than filter-query on color(:whilte) will be executed? How the above query will be executed?

Comment: The query isn't executed "across documents", it will find matching terms, then the intersection between those sets of documents will be calculated. The intersection between x and y number of documents is the same number as the intersection between y and x documents. However, using `fq` means that a _score_ won't be calculated for that set, so the computation is more effective.

Comment: @MatsLindh ... Thank you for your reply!   It means that a fuzzy search on the 'food' field is executed on the whole set of 20 million documents, what to do if I want to execute a fuzzy search only on 1 million documents having the color: white?

Comment: No, it's not executed against any documents; it's executed against the list of tokens present in the index. It does not really (in this stage) matter how many documents those tokens match. You need to think about this as sets - i.e. each query matches zero or more tokens, and from those tokens you get a set of document ids. That set is then intersected with the other set of document ids from the other part of the query. Whether set A or set B is large doesn't matter; they're still [1k document ids] vs [100k document ids] - they just swap sides but are still the same size.

Comment: What if i changed the query to ===> curl -G http://localhost:8983/solr/QueryPerformenceCore/select --data-urlencode "q=*:*" --data-urlencode "fq=(food:'cheese~' OR food:'paneer~' OR food:'milk~') AND (color:white)"...(If i don't want to calculate score for 'food' field, and only want fuzzy-search on 'food' field )...Still, will it execute against the whole list of tokens present in the index of the 'food' field (which I had done while indexing 20 million documents and each document is having 'food' field (required="true")), irrespective of whether 'color' is white or any other color?

Comment: If you don't need scores, using a `fq` for both queries will be better. You might also get better query performance by moving them to separate fqs, so that the result of the last fq can be cached separately (i.e. the different values for `color` are few, so Lucene/Solr only needs to cache the results of twenty different queries). You can quickly test if there are any optimizations that take place by swapping the sequence of the fqs around, but generally I don't think you'll see much (if any) change. I'm not familiar with the current internals in the query path.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can you direct me to the link that covers this, how the Solr-query is executed under the hood?

Comment: You'd be looking at Lucene internals, not (usually) Solr specific implementations as this is generally Lucene related details. The easiest way to start is by appending `debug=all` to your query to see exactly how your query gets evaluated and what gets retrieved and handled for each term. `lucene internals` is a good search query to start digging into lower level details about how Lucene works.